# About DatePart in Date functions

Tags: sql-server

I couldn't understand the difference between

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(D,'07/09/1978',GETDATE())

SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,'07/09/1978',GETDATE())
```

Both are giving the same value. Then what is the difference between D, and DD?

I have the same question for

- `M, MM`
- `Q, QQ`
- `YY, YYYY`

Can anybody please explain this to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a reference on dateparts and what they mean:

- [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) (MSDN)

As you can see, the examples you gave are all identical.  However, I know some experts like Aaron Bertrand advocate not using any of the abbreviations, but spelling out the datepart.

See his excellent post on this subject here:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)